# Чтение из файла, FileReader

Tags: java, строки

Есть файл.txt примерно  следующего содержания:

```
Дверь Окно  Лестница
1000  1200  2700
3     5     13
```

Нужно считать файл и сохранить в массив 3 объекта с параметрами, взятыми из файла.
Что-то вроде

```
Object ob = new Object(Name, Cost, Num);
array.add(ob);
```

Но никак не могу сообразить как распарить файл так, что бы правильно создать объект. Может быть кто подскажет? Значения в строке разделены пробелом, строки - знаком конца строки (`"\n"`). Буду рад помощи

Comment: Надо понимать что вы собираетесь парить и зачем. Не проще ли будет сохранить файл в известном формате, а затем парить его?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] wordsArr = null;
    try{
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\testout.txt"));

        String line = null;

        while(true){
            line = in.readLine();
            if(line == null){break;}
            else{
                wordsArr = line.split("\t");
                for(String x: wordsArr){
                    if(!"".equals(x)){
                        words.add(x);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        in.close();

    } catch(Exception x) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    String[] names = null;
    String[] costs = null;
    String[] nums = null;
    for(int i=0;i<1; i++){
        String lineOne = words.get(i);
        names = lineOne.split(" ");
    }
    for(int i=0;i<2; i++){
        String lineOne = words.get(i);
        costs = lineOne.split(" ");
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3; i++){
        String lineOne = words.get(i);
        nums = lineOne.split(" ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Считывание файла идёт построчно, т.е в 1-ой строке считываешь Stringи и кидаешь их в соответствуещее поле в своих объектах, потом так же и с остальными строками

Comment: Это и так понятно. Проблема в том, что у меня не получается сие реализовать

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class AppFile {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Map<Integer, ObjectTest> map = new HashMap<>();
            try (Scanner scanner =
                         new Scanner(AppFile.class.getResourceAsStream("/file.txt"))
            ) {

                int lineNumber = 1;
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                    String[] source = line.split(" ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
                        ObjectTest objectTest;
                        if (map.containsKey(i)) {
                            objectTest = map.get(i);
                        } else {
                            objectTest = new ObjectTest();
                        }

                        switch (lineNumber) {
                            case 1:
                                objectTest.setName(source[i]);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                objectTest.setCost(source[i]);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                objectTest.setNum(source[i]);
                                break;
                        }
                        map.put(i, objectTest);
                    }
                    lineNumber++;
                }
            }

            map.forEach((i, o) -> {
                System.out.printf("number: %s object name: %s\n", i, o.getName());
            });

        }
    }

    class ObjectTest {
        private String name;
        private String cost;
        private String num;

        public ObjectTest(String name, String cost, String num) {
            this.name = name;
            this.cost = cost;
            this.num = num;
        }

        public ObjectTest() {
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getCost() {
            return cost;
        }

        public void setCost(String cost) {
            this.cost = cost;
        }

        public String getNum() {
            return num;
        }

        public void setNum(String num) {
            this.num = num;
        }
    }
```

Вывод:
number: 0 object name: Дверь
number: 1 object name: Окно
number: 2 object name: Лестница